# How to dismiss a UISearchController from UINavigationItem?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController` with a `UICollectionView` filling the screen. In the `UINavigationBar` I have a button that shows a `UISearchBar` under the `UINavigationBar` when selected. I have this all working fine. The problem is that I can't get the search bar to dismiss when selecting the Cancel button on the `UISearchBar`. Here is my code:

```
var searchController = UISearchController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for Title"

    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
}

@IBAction func searchSelected(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    searchController.isActive = true
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print("cancel clicked")
    searchController.isActive = false
}
```

Comment: is the print("cancel clicked") being called?

Comment: Yes, "cancel clicked" is being called

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
navigationItem.searchController = nil
```